Configure multiple GCP pub/sub projects in single spring boot application
I am unable to find Google documentation of spring-cloud-gcp-stream-binder library to check how can we configure multiple GCP projects in a single spring boot reactive application to use respective GCP projects pub/sub topics for message sending and receiving. Could someone provide me the documentation and help me with configuration examples?
spring cloud GCP version: 4.8.4
spring cloud version: 2022.0.4
spring boot: 3.1.5
Unable to find the spring cloud GCP documentation related to examples/configuration of multiple GCP projects in a single spring boot reactive application.
